# How to remove left white border-color of my website

Tags: html, css, border

[image]

You can see a white border https://www.bdevg.com. See the border on the left side, it is not on the right side.

To create the wave animation I used a background image`(bottom wave of top section)` and it has a background color.

The whole section has the following style.

```css
paddingTop:"30px",
    position: 'relative',
    width: '100%',
    height: '60vh',
    background: '#556cd6', //#3544ff, #35aaff
    overflow: 'hidden',
    margin:"0px"
```

wave section has the following style

```css
height:"100px",
    width:"100%",
    position:"absolute",
    bottom:"0",
    left:"0",
    overflow:"hidden",
    backgroundImage:`url(/images/layout/wave.png)`,
    backgroundSize:"1000px 100px"
```

I tried to check padding or margin applied by other siblings and parent elements. But, i didn't found any way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on your navigation bar(expand the burger first) and inspect, it has a border-right property set

```
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorDockedLeft {
   border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); }
```

Simply remove that property and the white border will vanish.

Answer (score 1):

The white border is part of the side menu.

`.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorDockedLeft` is the reason why you see this white border. And this must be saved! Since this is part of the styling of the site:

```
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorDockedLeft {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

In order to keep this rule, you need to set the `left: -1px` rule in the `.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorLeft` selector. Do it like this:

```
.MuiDrawer-paperAnchorLeft {
    left: -1px;
    right: auto;
}
```